# How to convert mdb to mdf Database in Sql Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000 and Access 2003

I want to convert the database from access to sql Database.

There is possibility in sql server 2000 or any other tools is available.

Need Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access there is a Database Upsizing Wizard that will create a SQL Database and import all your data.

Comment: The SSMA tool from the SQL Server tool appears to be consideribly better than the Upsizing Wizard.

Comment: @Tony: Have you compared the SSMA results to simply exporting the table directly to the ODBC database?

Comment: Didn't know about SSMA I used the Access way about ten years ago. It is one answer, but I would definitely use SSMA from now on. Thanks Tony

Answer (score 3):

There is a  tool from the SQL Server group.
[SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access (SSMA Access)](http://www.microsoft.com/sql/solutions/migration/access/default.mspx)